# Javascript - get filesize or catch error in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-upload

I want to **get file size** using javascript or **catch error** if some browser no support. IE 10 support, ie 9, 8 ... not support

 I using but not working. How can i do that thanks

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><!-- not working -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1"><!-- not working -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" ><!-- not working -->

<input type="file" id="myFile" />
```

```
if (document.getElementById('myFile').files[0]){
     // do something
} else {// can't catch to print 
   alert('don't support');
}
```

Comment: You might want to do this check first: `if ("files" in document.createElement("input")) {`. Then inside, you can use `document.getElementById('myFile').files[0]`

Comment: @lan i don't know this code if ("files" in document.createElement("input")). (note: my input tag can't change or create by another code)

Comment: It's to test for support of the `files` property. If that `if` condition passes, you can use your `document.getElementById('myFile').files[0]` code

Comment: @lan sorry but i don't know correct code of if ("files" in document.createElement("input")) that's Pseudocode and  my input tag can't change or create by another code (your idea is create input tag by document.createElement("input") ?)

Comment: It's not pseudocode - it was a generic way to determine if the browser supports the `files` property, which is what I thought your point was. The input tag I created was simply for testing. Like I said, you'd still target your specific element and work with it. Here's more or less what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/8xpSh/1/

Comment: thanks u it's so good to check browser if not support

Comment: No problem! So does that answer (all of) your questions? Or do you need more help? If it's enough, I'll post an answer

Comment: @lan my question have 2 case that are get file size and catch error. your code to test all browsers? if it test all browsers thank u :) and 2nd case of my question will be done

Comment: @lan if my 1st case can't do by anyway please tell me and you can post answer thanks :)